# $\log _{-3}\left( 9 \right)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Can you have a negative base for a logarithm? If the answer is no, why can you not? Isn't the answer to the above just $2$?

Similarly, is $-3$ also a solution to the equation $\log _{x}\left( 9 \right)\; =\; 2$ (I know one solution is obviously 3).

Comment: And what would be $\log_{-3}(8)$ equal to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition $\log_{-3}(x)$ would be the $y$ such that $(-3)^y=x$. The trouble here is that $(-3)^y$ is not well-defined unless $y$ is an integer, so you won't be able to solve this for very many different $x$.

Even if you say that $(-3)^y$ is meaningful whenever $y$ is rational with odd denominator, this only gives you countably many different $x$ for which $\log_{-3}(x)$ can exist, so it won't behave very much like ordinary logarithms. (The corresponding antilogarithm wouldn't be continuous, for example).

Comment: Logarithms with negative bases or negatives arguments are always complex functions. $log_{-3}(9) = { {log(9)} \over {log(3) + \pi i}} = {{log 3 log 9 - \pi i log 9} \over {log 3 log 3 + \pi \pi}}$

Comment: @Arucard: The trouble with that is $-3$ have many different complex logarithms, and each of those gives rise to a _different_ $\log_{-3}$ function, even before we begin to consider the branch point of the logarithm in the denominator.

Answer (score 5):

By definition for $a>0$ we have
$$\log_a(x)=\frac{\log_e(x)}{\log_e(a)}$$
where 
$$\log_e(x)=\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$$

Comment: Short but to the point: nails it! +1

Comment: Congratulations!! $\Large > 30\text K$!!!